# How do i make it default to the A1 cell instead of selecting the whole row after splitting data?

Tags: excel, vba

How do i make it default to the A1 cell instead of selecting the whole row after splitting data?

```
Sub SplitData()
Const lngTMCol = 1 ' names in second column (A)
Const lngFirstRow = 2 ' data start in row 2
Dim wshSource As Worksheet
Dim wbkTarget As Workbook
Dim wshTarget As Worksheet
Dim lngRow As Long
Dim lngLastRow As Long
Dim lngTargetRow As Long
Dim strPath As String
Dim strName As String
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
strPath = ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\"
Set wshSource = ActiveSheet
lngLastRow = wshSource.Cells(wshSource.Rows.Count, lngTMCol).End(xlUp).Row
For lngRow = lngFirstRow To lngLastRow
    If wshSource.Cells(lngRow, lngTMCol).Value <> wshSource.Cells(lngRow - 1, lngTMCol).Value Then
        If lngRow > lngFirstRow Then
            ' Save previous new workbook
            wbkTarget.SaveAs Filename:=strPath & strName, FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook
            wbkTarget.Close
        End If
        ' Create new workbook
        Set wbkTarget = Workbooks.Add(xlWBATWorksheet)
        Set wshTarget = wbkTarget.Worksheets(1)
        strName = wshSource.Cells(lngRow, lngTMCol).Value
        wshTarget.Name = strName
        wshSource.Range("1:2").Copy Destination:=wshTarget.Cells(1, 1)
        wshSource.Range("2:2").Copy
        wshTarget.Range("2:2").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteColumnWidths
        lngTargetRow = lngFirstRow
    End If
    ' Copy data
    wshSource.Rows(lngRow).Copy Destination:=wshTarget.Cells(lngTargetRow, 1)
    lngTargetRow = lngTargetRow + 1
Next lngRow
' Save last workbook
wbkTarget.SaveAs Filename:=strPath & strName, FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook
wbkTarget.Close
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```

[How do i make it default to the A1 cell instead of selecting the whole row after splitting data?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NoTZo.png)

Comment: `Activate` the sheet and `Select` the first cell in that row?

Comment: How should I do it. Sorry am a noob. Thanks for helping.

Comment: Which worksheet is this? `wshSource` or `wshTarget`?

Comment: wshtarget - thanks bigben for helping

Comment: `wshTarget.Activate`, `wshTarget.Range("A2").Select`

Comment: sorry ben, i keep getting error. Do u mind posting the whole script of how it look like? Appreciate your help